# How to resolve flutter errors in all files

Tags: flutter, dart, runtime-error

I am getting a lot of errors in my flutter project I don't know why and how it happened
[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried flutter pub get commands to fix the dependencies but didn't work

```
 this is my pubspec.yaml file
```

name: growmore
description: A new Flutter project.

## The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to

## pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

## The following defines the version and build number for your application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: '>=2.18.4 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
pinput: ^2.2.16
firebase_core: ^2.2.0
firebase_auth: ^4.1.2
firebase_database: ^10.0.6
google_sign_in: ^5.4.2
govt_documents_validator: ^0.0.1
flutter_localizations:
sdk: flutter
flutter_form_builder: ^7.7.0
form_builder_validators: ^8.4.0
image_picker: ^0.8.6
firebase_storage: ^11.0.6
cloud_firestore: ^4.1.0
flutter_riverpod: ^2.1.1
contact_picker: ^0.0.2
quickalert: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

Comment: I faced same problem,just restart vscode

Comment: still they are occuring, please help me this can ruine my whole project

Comment: can you run flutter doctor -v and check if there is something missing, and check over flutter and dart extensions on vscode

Comment: if this also didn't work, try deleting re-enabling flutter extension vscode

Comment: if this also did not work, try running flutter clean on command line, to delete the build folder, then run flutter pub get to get again the dependencies

Comment: this seems to be a vscode / flutter bug, it happened to me yesterday, and a quick restart just fixed it.

Comment: nothing in flutter doctor -v all clear

Comment: I am getting same error in android studio as well

Comment: not even in this I am getting error in any flutter app